# Line break in span

Tags: javascript, html, css, word-wrap, line-breaks

```css
.heading {
  font-weight: bold;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: auto;
  font-stretch: extra-expanded !important;
  overflow: hidden;
  
  display: inline-block !important;
  word-wrap: break-word !important;
  word-break: break-all !important;
  white-space: normal;

}
.heading span {
  font-size: 1.1rem !important;
  word-break: break-all !important;

  display: inline-block !important;
  width: -webkit-max-content;
  width: -moz-max-content;
  width: max-content;
  word-wrap: break-word !important;
  /* margin: 0; */
  display: block !important;
  white-space: normal;
  /* line-height: 57px; */
}
```

```html
              <span class="heading"><span class="appear">WORD1WORD1 WORD2WORD2</span></span>
              <span class="heading"><span class="appear">WORD1WORD1   WORD2WORD2</span></span> 
              <span class="heading"><span class="appear">WORD1WORD1 WORD2WORD2</span></span>
```

My span words are getting displayed as a group and don't insert line break after a word if required. Since I am animating these words together, I need to keep them in a single span element. I have tried the tricks of word-wrap but they don't seem to work.

Comment: If i am understanding this right, means you need to insert line break, then you can use the html `<br>` tag

Comment: These span elements are a part of paragraphs so I would like to insert line break wherever required eg. if one of the words can be displayed on one line and the other word on the next line, a line break is inserted instead of displaying the entire span block in a new line.

Comment: What is the outcome you're trying to achieve? Do you want one word on each line? Or do you want the words to split so that part of a word is on one line and the rest is on the next? What you're describing where words break to the new line if they don't fit is default functionality which is already occurring in your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `white-space: pre-line;` to the `.appear` class so the words are broken when line breaks are added.

```css
.heading {
  font-weight: bold;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: auto;
  font-stretch: extra-expanded !important;
  overflow: hidden;
  
  display: inline-block !important;
  word-wrap: break-word !important;
  word-break: break-all !important;
  white-space: normal;

}
.appear {
  white-space: pre-line;
}
.heading span {
  font-size: 1.1rem !important;
  word-break: break-all !important;

  display: inline-block !important;
  width: -webkit-max-content;
  width: -moz-max-content;
  width: max-content;
  word-wrap: break-word !important;
  /* margin: 0; */
  display: block !important;
  /* white-space: normal; */ remove white-space here
  /* line-height: 57px; */
}
```

```html
<span class="heading"><span class="appear">WORD1WORD1 WORD2WORD2</span></span>
<span class="heading"><span class="appear">WORD1WORD1   
WORD2WORD2
</span></span> 
<span class="heading"><span class="appear">WORD1WORD1 WORD2WORD2</span></span>
```